# In C/C++ is x[i] * y[i++] always equal to x[i] * y[i]

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)
>   [increment values in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492043/increment-values-in-printf)

I have a two double arrays `x` and `y` and integer `i`. My question is whether the statement:

```
double res = x[i] * y[i++];
```

is always equal to the statement:

```
double res = x[i] * y[i];
i++;
```

Is it possible that some compilers would change `x[i] * y[i++]` into `y[i++] * x[i]`, which obviously produces different result?

Comment: Why does it matter? If you want a specific order, just write it in that order.

Comment: @BoPersson. I thought to write explanation why I need it, but didn't want to spoil the question. Shortly, I need to accelerate `double vectors_dot_product(double *x, double *y, int n);` function, and found that `x[i] * y[i++] + x[i] * y[i++] + ...;` is faster than `x[i] * y[i] + x[i+1] * y[i+1] + ...;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No -- `x[i] + y[i++]` has undefined behavior. You're modifying the value of `i` and also using the value `i` without an intervening sequence point, which gives undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>.

---

1. In C++11 the standard has eliminated the "sequence point" terminology, but the effect remains the same -- the two are unordered with respect to each other.

Comment: +1 first answer with correct language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the commutativity of the multiplication operator. If the operation was `x[i] - y[i++]` (which can't be reversed), the behavior of `i` in this situation would still be undefined.

Answer (score 8):

No, it is undefined when the increment occurs.

Comment: Not just when the increment occurs. The behavior is **entirely** undefined: it modifies `i` and reads its value without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @Pete: Great, when will the pizza delivery boy show up at my doorstep? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow - ask your compiler vendor.

Answer (score 6):

The code modifies `i` and uses its value without an intervening sequence point, so the behavior is undefined. The language definition does not impose any requirements here.

Comment: Interesting that you, of all people, wouldn't mention the fact that C++11 no longer uses "sequence point". :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin - sometimes it's better to keep things simple.

Comment: +1. There's something to be said for the simplicity of "abandon faith, all ye who enter here".

Answer (score 1):

No,

value of i++ + i++ are  [undefined](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order) in `C` and `C++`.

if you read a variable twice in an expression where you also write it, the result is undefined. Don't do that. Another example is:

```
v[i] = i++;
```

Undefined means its COMPILER DEPENDENT.
Some compiler could warn you also as undefined because the order of evaluation. 
A very good [reference](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order) for C++

[1](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order) http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order

Comment: Still needs a bit of work -- `v[i] = i++;` is undefined even though it may not involve any function or passing arguments at all.

Comment: @Serg: Welcome serg !  I glad if I can help :)

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Thanks for informing...It mention in the link I provided.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - sorry to pile on, but this is **not** about order of evaluation. The order of evaluation of function arguments is **unspecified**, which means that it is compiler dependent: the compiler can arbitrarily choose an order. Here there are no function arguments to be evaluated. The behavior is **undefined**, which means all bets are off. In a sense it's compiler dependent, since it obviously depends on the code the compiler generates, but the code that the compiler generates (if it does...) doesn't have to do anything sensible.